# python, extract outer most brackets

Tags: python

I have the following code which tries to extract msgids from a template files:

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = '''p=t("Because of the high quality surface finish, our garments perform particularly well with digital direct-to-garment (DTG) printing.")'''
>>> string2 = '''p=t("The carbon footprint (CO2e) is the total carbon dioxide, methane, nitrous oxide, and other greenhouse gases emitted during the cultivation and harvesting of cotton, fibre processing, textile production, packaging, transportation and warehousing. In January 2008, Clothing Co.  became the first company in the world to calculate the carbon footprint and place the Carbon Reduction Label on textile products.")'''
>>> string3 = '''USER_REGISTERED_AND_ACTIVE: "The email address entered is already registered. <br>Please <a href='/login'>(Login)</a>"'''
>>> string4 = '''p!=t("We received your application to become an additional user for an account on <strong>__date__</strong>.")'''
>>> string5 = '''p=#{t("We received your order on")}'''
>>> gettext_messages = re.compile(r"""\:(.*)""", re.MULTILINE).findall
>>> for string in [string1, string2, string3, string4, string5]:
...     msgids = gettext_messages(string)
...     print msgids
... 
[]
[]
[' "The email address entered is already registered. <br>Please <a href=\'/login\'>(Login)</a>"']
[]
[]
>>> gettext_re = re.compile(r"""[=|#]t\((.*?)\)""").findall
>>> for string in [string1, string2, string3, string4, string5]:
...     msgids = gettext_re(string)
...     print msgids
... 
['"Because of the high quality surface finish, our garments perform particularly well with digital direct-to-garment (DTG']
['"The carbon footprint (CO2e']
[]
['"We received your application to become an additional user for an account on <strong>__date__</strong>."']
[]
```

This works to a point, in that if a string contains another set of `( )` then it fails.

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: Please post only relevant code - something we can play with.

Answer (score 1):

ok, it should be, like

```
gettext_re = re.compile(r"""[=|#|{]t\((.*?)\"\)""").findall
```